# Getting a custom built financial software system under test automation

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, tdd

I am needing to get a financials heavy software system under test automation. It has been in development and production for a couple years. I've been an advocate for developers building testing test automation into their coding practices for over 18 years, but this is a unique challenge. Beyond establishing test automation standards and training for the technologies we are using, I need to figure out the most effective strategy for prioritizing and implementing automated tests into the existing system that will improve confidence/stability/reliability, while continuing with rapid development of future features. There are many teams working on this solution.

My primary decision point is whether I should start the focus on internals of the financial transactions, processes, rules - with unit and integration tests under the hood -  or start with use cases that tell full stories. There are two things that are competing for priority, making sure requirements have been implemented correctly vs. making sure what has already been implemented does NOT get broken by new code merges. I realize that these are not mutually exclusive, but time is of the essence and I need to move yesterday on implementing the highest value tests.

I would love to discuss with others experienced with test automation in systems that are heavy on financial transactions that are CRITICAL.

Comment: Robert Martins boy scout rule is always useful: "Always leave the campground cleaner than you found it." In other words: Test what you touch. If this is too much, then at least factor out the bit you touch and test that. Note: testing existing code is not TDD, since tests are written after the fact. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you will never catch up with the tests you should focus on new features and fixes. Whenever the code will be changed, try to identify which parts of the existing code will be touched and see if you can improve the test coverage for this parts before writing any new code. Do not aim for perfection, just try to get some tests running that would catch any serious regressions. Then try to TDD the new feature/fix.

Also check out "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael Feathers.